# Where is onActivityResult() in androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity?

Tags: androidx

AndriodX activities extend androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity but that object chain doesn't include onActivityResult( requestCode, resultCode, data).  In other words, you can't override it because it's not there.

How do you get the result of a startActivityForResult() if there's no way to add a listener?

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
```

I'm confused because

```
androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
```

extends

```
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity
```

which contains

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable
```

Intent data) { ... }

which I should be able to override.  Is this somehow because I'm using Kotlin?

Answer (score 5):

I answered my own question.  Yes, it's Kotlin, and I'm still not used to some of the effects of calling java from kotlin.  It's mostly the same, but Intent isnullable, which should have signaled me that I need to do this:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
   ...
}
```

noting that the type is *Intent?* to match the nullable parameter.  Whoops!